# Can't change background color of django form field

Tags: css, django, django-forms

I'm trying to change background colors of django form field using `widget attrs` like below.

**forms.py**

```py
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    a_filed = forms.EmailField(
                  widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class':'black-input'}))
```

It produces an *html* element in a template with class name `"black-input"` as expected.

**html**

```html
<input type="email" name="email" class="black-input" id="id_email">
```

Elements with the name `"black-input"` should show up with black background color as I set `{background-color:black}` in my css file.

**main.css**

```css
.black-input{
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: black;
    color: rgba(177, 177, 177, .8);
    border: none;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
```

But css doesn't change anything about background color. The weird part is that css changes other attributes of the element (*border*, *border-radius*, *padding*). Of course I checked how the css behaves, and it changed background color of other input elements (ones not produced through django forms) on the same template with the class name of `"black-input"`.

Comment: Does `background-color: black !important;` work? if so, it means this styling is being overridden elsewhere in your stylesheet.

Comment: Thank you solarissmoke. I just tried it now and it didn't change the color.